# sqlite with Python is unreasonably slow compared to anydbm

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, dbm

My goal is to create a database of MD5 hashes, and then check another list of hashes against it to see if they exist in the database.

I have a working solution using `anydbm`, which if you are unfamiliar works exactly like a dictionary in python, but you don't have to load the whole thing in memory at once.  Creation of the db is rather slow (100 million entries in roughly 2 and a half hours) and retrieval speed is moderate (100000 entries in 1 to 2 seconds). Checking if the hash exists is as simple as `if hash in dbm`.

For a performance improvement, I attempted to make a working solution with sqlite.  Creation speed is blazing fast, creating all 100 million entries in a few minutes.  But retrieval took upwards of 15 seconds for *one entry*.  This is unreasonable!

I'm not a SQL pro, so I'm wondering if I'm just using commands which overly complicate things.

They are as follows:

creation of table: `c.execute('''create table keys(id integer not null primary key autoincrement, hash text, alert text) ''')`

adding entries(in a loop): `c.execute('''insert into keys(hash, alert) values (?,?) ''', (hash, "1"))`

retrieval(also looped):

```
c.execute('''select * from keys where hash = ? ''', (hash,))
hits = c.fetchall() 
numhits += len(hits)
```

Comment: sqlite is not for performance.

Comment: [Index your `hash` column.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

Comment: Doing a `select *` from a non-indexed, non-unique field causes the database to scan every record in the queried table, whereas a hash-based lookup with unique keys like a dictionary/`anydbm` key:value store only stores each key once, so only 1 record needs to be found. As @Carsten said, you need to use an index to make your queries faster (and consider adding a unique constraint if possible).

Comment: The MD5 hashes will not be unique in the source document, but I don't necessarily need to keep every entry.  Is there a way I can set it up so that the hashes are unique, but if I try to add a duplicate it simply ignores the op?

Comment: I haven't used this clause, but it looks like what you need: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html ... use the IGNORE statement

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: as for sqlite performance, I think you should egt some benchmarks and citations. It is not for concurrence or scalability - but single accss performance it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create an index on your md5 table - no matter if the hashes are not unique - not having an index means a linear access throw all the records at each access.

Looking at the docs, it looks like creating your index is as easy as issuing 
`CREATE INDEX hash ON keys (hash)` on your database.